# How to input variable in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this if condition where if you're input "[first_name]" in the text field the result will be "John". But if you're input "Hello [first_name]" the result will be "Hello [first_name]".

Here's the code, i know if you're input only "[first_name]" in text field it works. But how do i fix this if i write whatever in the text field the result would be what i write and the variable "[first_name]" would be "John". Thank you.

```
<p> Input [first_name] for variable </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<p id="result"></p>

function myFunction(){
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var myVar = "[first_name]"
    
    if (input == myVar){
        var data = document.getElementById('result').value= "John"
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = input
    }
}
```

**What Did I Tried**
*Input field*:
Hello [first_name]
*Result:*
Hello [first_name]

**What I'm Expecting**
*Input field*:
Hello [first_name]
*Result:*
Hello John

or whatever i write in the text field with variable "[first_name]" would be "John" and another text that i write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your JavaScript code slightly. Instead of comparing the entire input string with **"[first_name]"**, you should check if **"[first_name]"** is present in the input string using the **indexOf()** method. Here's the modified code:

```js
function myFunction(){
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var myVar = "[first_name]";
    
    if (input.indexOf(myVar) !== -1){
        var data = input.replace(myVar, "John");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = input;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Input [first_name] for variable</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Consider using `.replaceAll`

Answer (score 1):

Input [first_name] for variable

```
<input id="myInput" type="text"> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button> 
<p id="result"></p>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var myVar = "[first_name]";
  var result = input.replace(myVar, "John");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Consider `.replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var myVar = "[first_name]";
  if (input == myVar) {
    var data = (document.getElementById("result").value = "John");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = input.replace(
      myVar,
      "John"
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Input [first_name] for variable</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Consider using `.replaceAll`